# Integrate Android App with ADB Daemon

Tags: android, adb, daemon

I have a requirement to integrate an android application with the ADB Daemon in order to pass commands to it (my Android application) through the USB interface.

Is this possible ?

My intention, is to plug this Android device to a Linux device and allow the Linux device to pass commands to the Android application via USB.

Therefore, since ADB is already implemented, and the ADB drivers for Linux also exist, I was wondering whether it would be easier to leverage this to allow the kind of communication I require.

Comment: AFAIK the vice-versa of your requirement is possible.

Comment: Hi Zax, could you kindly share how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Activity Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am) through adb shell.
For example, "adb shell am broadcast " will send broadcast intent to attached device.
Then your app can handle it with broadcast receiver.